# Magento 2.X not getting success page when used authorized.net payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, authorize.net, checkout-page, place-order

Now i am using another magento 2.0.2. I want to test authorized.net and set API login id and transaction id, test mode "YES", gateway URL is https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll , transactional detail URL is null and set test mode on authorized.net. now result is transaction has been approved and order has placed successfully in admin but not redirecting on success or failure page. what can i do.

Comment: I don't get success page. I do get my card captured/charged but no Thank you page. Error on the server... whats up?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146766)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146766)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the issues with authorize.net payment method. If you want to use direct post authorize.net payment method then you need to check on live site with https domain. and you will check with live credentials. you will get success page after place order.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing different issues like some time it's a redirect to cart page instead of success page but an order placed in the admin.